# Bite vs Blood Infection

Tags: the-walking-dead

When people get bit they turn into zombies however when they kill a zombie in close quarters, their face, mouth, eyes, nose and any cuts they have exposed get covered in zombie blood but they don't get infected. Is infection in their teeth or blood....?

Comment: Also see [Why hasn't Michonne turned in The Walking Dead?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27058/why-hasnt-michonne-turned-in-the-walking-dead).

Comment: In the movie World War Z, there is a mention that North Korea orders for removing all the teeth of its citizens so that the virus doesn't spread .

Comment: and [In Walking Dead (TV), is it possible that a survivor becomes immune](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34023/5184)

Comment: @kartik While that may be true, this question is about *The Walking Dead*, specifically - not *World War Z*. What is true in one story/universe is not necessarily true in the next.

Comment: The question @calccrypto links contains the answer to this question. Everyone is _already_ infected, so walker blood fountains don't matter.